# UIButton disappears on runtime

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a `UIButton` beneath a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`. I have used the suggested constraints in Interface Builder and in the preview loaded by clicking the Assistant Editor, the view looks exactly like I want it to.

[image]

But when the app is run, the button appears for a split second before disappearing. At first I assumed it was because the button was below the table view in the hierarchy (it was), and I fixed that. But even now, I am facing the same issue. Here are my constraints:

[image]

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: you don't want the following constraint `Close incident.top = Bottom Layout Guide.top` Please remove and see if its solved

Comment: @JožeWs No, that did not work either.

Comment: do you have any constraint errors, compile-time or runtime?

Answer (score 0):

For your `UIButton`, delete existing constraints and add the following constraints,

1. Top
2. Bottom
3. Leading
4. Trailing

Make sure the vertical spacing between button and table view is 0

Comment: Okay pls try lowering the height of table view, or if you have a bottom constraint, make the constant bigger to see if the button is really there. Strange. Have you, anywhere made the `isHidden` property to true for the button?

Comment: Nope. Strangely, when I disable AutoLayout, the button appears and works perfectly fine. But obviously, that isn't a permanent solution.

Comment: I've faced weird issues like these in the past. As a last resort, I just delete everything and build the view controller from scratch, and most times that worked for me. If you don't have any clue, just for ticking an option, you could backup the existing VC and just build a new VC from scratch.